# android dialog alert

Tags: android, dialog, alert

i m newbie in programming. Really appreciate if someone willing to answer my question.
I have a rotating galleryview at the back. But when a dialog alert come out is there any method can be used to "freeze" the rotation of the gallery view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Your message goes here.");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
```